# Process not working

Tags: c#, .net, process

I have tried calling a Process(console application) using the following code:

```
       ProcessStartInfo pi = new ProcessStartInfo();
        pi.UseShellExecute = false;
        pi.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
        pi.CreateNoWindow = true;
        pi.FileName = @"C:\fakepath\go.exe";
        pi.Arguments = "FOO BAA";
        Process p = Process.Start(pi);
        StreamReader streamReader = p.StandardOutput;
        char[] buf = new char[256];
        string line = string.Empty;
        int count;
        while ((count = streamReader.Read(buf, 0, 256)) > 0)
        {
            line += new String(buf, 0, count);
        }
```

It works for only some cases. 
The file that does not work has a size of 1.30 mb,
I don't know if that is the reason for it not working correctly.
  `line` returns an empty string.
I hope this is clear.
Can someone point out my error? Thanks in advance.

Comment: What form does the failure take?

Comment: For this case,returns an empty string.
I tested with the exec() function(calling the same proccess) of PHP,works fine.

Comment: Don't know C# and this isn't the problem but there seems to be an unbalanced `"` in the line containing `BAA`.

Comment: Sorry, because I edited some variables in textbox here. fixed.
but the code continue not working.

Comment: Doesn't the program output anything to `StandardError`?

Comment: @svick: Huh? What is that relevant?

Comment: Do you get non-empty results if you manually execute the command against that file?  Also, can you edit your question to add exactly what failure you're getting, rather than just leaving it in comments?

Comment: @Tom, maybe The Mask is doing something wrong and reading the error stream would reveal what that is.

Comment: @svick: `StandardError was not redirected.`

Comment: @The Mask, and did you try doing that? Maybe the program writes some error message there that could help you.

Comment: Oh, I see, window-based, you have to do something special to get your error messages.

Comment: @Merlyn: I can calling this same proccess using PHP, works fine.I edited my question adding the error.

Comment: Try printing the length of `line` each time through the loop (which also shows whether it's looping), may provide some insight into what's happening.

Comment: @svick: Well,I'll try do this.

Comment: @Tom:I did this, this: streamReader.Read(buf, 0, 256) returns 0, the loop is not run. :(

Comment: I' tried: 

    `pi.RedirectStandardError = true; `

and 
printing 
`p.StandardError.ReadToEnd()`

not there error message

Comment: Is it possible you don't have permissions to access the program or that file from the app you are running?  This might happen if you're running this code from Asp.Net (?)

Answer (score 2):

A couple thoughts:

1. The various Read* methods of streamreader require you to ensure that your app has completed before they run, otherwise you may get no output depending on timing issues.   You may want to look at the Process.WaitForExit() function if you want to use this route.

   Also, unless you have a specific reason for allocating buffers (pain in the butt IMO) I would just use readline() in a loop, or since the process has exited, ReadToEnd() to get the whole output.  Neither requires you to have to do arrays of char, which opens you up to math errors with buffer sizes.
2. If you want to go asynchronous and dump output as you run, you will want to use the BeginOutputReadLine() function (see MSDN)
3. Don't forget that errors are handled differently, so if for any reason your app is writing to STDERR, you will want to use the appropriate error output functions to read that output as well.